# Referencing WPF Control Class in same assembly in Resource Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, xml-namespaces

I have a class that extends the System.Windows.Controls.Control that I intend to turn into a custom control for use in my WPF application like so:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class CustomControl : Control
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

All Windows and code files use the MyNamespace namespace, whether it is a xaml file, or a .cs file. So it should be easy to reference this class in the same namespace (MyNamespace) like so:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.CustomWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlsn:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        Title="MyCustomWindow">
    <Grid>
        <local:CustomControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But when I do this, I get an error saying:

`The name "CustomControl" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyNamespace"`

However, if I have another custom control defined in another assembly, I can add it fine like so:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.CustomWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlsn:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        xmlns:otherAssembly="clr-namespace:OtherNamespace;assembly=OtherAssembly"
        Title="MyCustomWindow">
    <Grid>
        <otherAssembly:OtherCustomControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How do I get my Mynamespace.CustomControl to work in my xaml?

Comment: Is it an error during compilation or a squiggly line during design time?

Comment: It's a design time squiggly error. It runs ok, but I want to resolve the root of the problem if possible so I'm not wondering what's going on when I get bugs.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me once i Pressed F7 to compile in Visual Studio Community 2015, before i compiled the project the first custom control shows that error.